# Does Pro Tools (or any other DAW) have a feature like Logic's Quick Swipe Comping?

Tags: audio, logic-pro, daw, pro-tools

I am working on a project in Logic 9 that involves quick swipe comping of phase-locked audio tracks.  I won't go into the details but I have had many problems over many projects when they involve multi-mic phase-locked tracks that need to be comped in take folders.  Logic is my first DAW, but I am becoming frustrated with unpredictable behavior with take folders (I also have a lot of problems with unpredictable behavior in flex time).

Does Pro Tools have an analogous function to Logic 9's "Quick Swipe Comping"?  If so, what is it called?

Are there other DAW's that have implemented something analogous to Logic's Quick Swipe comping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: PreSonus Studio One 2.5
http://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=studio+one+2+comping&FORM=VIRE6#view=detail&mid=D88B3D12326D32548B59D88B3D12326D32548B59

Or: Cakewalk Sonar X3
https://www.cakewalk.com/products/sonar/whats-new.aspx

Comment: Both of these look promising.  I need to expand my DAW horizons.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Pro Tools has something extremely similar.

Unlike Pro Tools, Logic does not have playlists. The easiest way to look at a 'playlist' is simply as a 'take'.

In Pro Tools, you can either record over the previously recorded region, or each recording can have its own playlist. Even if you didn't use playlists initially, it is easy to tell Pro Tools to create a playlist per take.

Once the takes are in playlists, you can unfold them (choosing 'playlists' as the track view) - seeing all the takes just like in quick comp in Logic. The only difference is that while in Logic making a selection puts it in the comp, in Pro Tools you need to make a selection and then explicitly copy it to the comp (there's a keyboard shortcut for that, so it's really quick).

This [video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hMmj9PuX7S0) shows how it is done.

Answer (score 0):

As this SE forum is a bit quiet, I asked the question on Avid's forum as well and received this answer "in a word, no."

http://duc.avid.com/showthread.php?t=347327